# How to tell if something can be split python

Tags: python

Is there any way to tell if something can be split without a try and except block?
Lets say I have something like this

```
stringOne = "Hello there how are you"
stringTwo = ["hello","how","are","you"]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
def fun(word):
    return "".join(["%s!" % x for x in word]) if len(word.split()) == 0 else "".join(word)
fun(stringTwo)
```

So any way to see if something can be split? like string.isdigit() or something similar?

Comment: Your stringTwo is not even a string. Maybe all you want is to check a type of your variable?

Comment: The Pythonic way to do it is with a `try`-`except` block.

Comment: @WaleedKhan The _real_ Pythonic way to do it is with type introspection (`isinstance`) falling back to metaobject protocol evaluation -- `if 'split' in dir(object):` Note: I am joking. Do not do this in production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if something's a string with `isinstance(object, basestring)`. This'll catch both `str` and `unicode`:

```
In [1]: isinstance("foo", basestring)
Out[1]: True

In [2]: isinstance(["foo"], basestring)
Out[2]: False

In [3]: isinstance(u"foo", basestring)
Out[3]: True
```